# Why xpra html5 client dont show client's local printer and regular xpra desktop client does?

Tags: html, ubuntu, x11, printers

I am using xpra on lubuntu16.04 , I used the below command to start `xpra`:

```
xpra start :5007 --start-child=leafpad --html=on --bind-tcp=0.0.0.0:44444 -d printing --encoding=jpeg
```

After starting xpra, when I connect from chrome using `192.168.x.x:44444` ip in urlbar, leafpad application shows on chrome tab but when I press `ctrl + p` on same tab it shows list of default printers of lubuntu16.04 machine but dont show printers of my machine.

Also when I tried to connect using simple xpra desktop client from my windows machine with `192.168.x.x:44444` ip, leafpad opens with new window on my windows desktop & on press of `ctrl + p` it shows my local windows machine printers as expected.

So my question why in webbrowser (html5 client) it can't show local machine printer and why xpra desktop client shows it, what is difference between this two html5 client and xpra desktop client?

Can any one explain if I want to list local printer in html5 client than what are neccessary steps for it?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Will html5 client be able to list client's local printers in browser and print on it](https://www.xpra.org/trac/ticket/1572):

> Browsers do not allow Javascript code to query the hardware.
>   (just to clarify: printing from the HTML5 client should already work, and the print dialog should allow you to choose the printer - but this all happens within the brower's UI, client side)